# Velocity, check if custom field has certain value

Tags: jira, velocity

I'm using plugin "Email this issue" to customize email notifications. I need to add to subject some custom fields, with a label. I want to omit the label if the field (a String) is empty.

This is my subject:

```
$!issue.summary#if($!mailSubject) $!mailSubject#end EU:#renderCustomField($issue, 'customfield_12752') RES:#renderCustomField($issue, 'customfield_11734') DIS:#renderCustomField($issue, 'customfield_11735')
```

If custom field is empty string or null the corrisponding label should be omitted.

Example: custom field 1275 and 11735 are empty.

This is how my subject results:

```
summary mailsubject EU: RES: xyz DIS:
```

This is how subject should result:

```
summary mailsubject RES: xyz
```

Comment: Can you explain bit more ?`#if($!somevalue)` enough to check empty.

Comment: @soorapadman I've edited the question. Isn't #if($!somevalue) valid only for jira fields? What is the sintax for custom fields?

Answer (score 0):

From the input what you must have to check is you shouldn't have print the label if empty . To avoid the You have to put if condition around the label.

```
#if($!val){
Your value:val
}
```

To Check your changes You must have to follow suggestion given by the jira by following URL [here](https://metainf.atlassian.net/wiki/display/PLUG/Velocity+Context+in+Email+Templates) and [this](https://metainf.atlassian.net/wiki/display/PLUG/Add+Fields+to+Email+Templates). one more link suggestion to given by this [issue](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/Velocity-simple-null-check/qaq-p/504544)

So your code must follow this way to work your condition

```
$!issue.summary
            #if($!mailSubject)
                $!mailSubject
             #end
          // You can set the value to a variable and check the null condition      
            #set($eu = $!jetiFieldRenderer.renderCustomField($issue, 'customfield_12752')))
              //In in this cass if null it will go to inside
                #if($!eu)
                    EU:#renderCustomField($issue, 'customfield_12752')
                #end
               #set($res= $!jetiFieldRenderer.renderCustomField($issue, 'customfield_11734'))
                #if($res)
                    RES:#renderCustomField($issue, 'customfield_11734')
                #end
            #set($dis=$!jetiFieldRenderer.renderCustomField($issue, 'customfield_11735'))
               #if($dis)
               #end
            DIS:#renderCustomField($issue, 'customfield_11735')
         #end
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
    #set ($ln = $customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObjectByName('CustomTextField'))
    #if($issue.getCustomFieldValue($ln))
    $issue.getCustomFieldValue($ln)
    #end
```

hope it helps